# f:$\mathbb{R}\rightarrow\mathbb{R}$. Given that, $f(f(f(x)))=x$, prove that the function is bijective.

Tags: functions

I have proved that the function is one-one by the following method:---
If we assume,
$f(x)=f(y)$
Then, $f(f(f(x)))=f(f(f(y)))$
Or, $x=y$
But how can I prove that the function is onto?
Also, please tell me how to prove a function to be onto in general.

Comment: Why not just find the inverse function $g(x)$ such that $f(g(x))=g(f(x))=x$ for all $x$?

Comment: To prove a function $f$ is onto, given $x$ you have to produce a $y$ such that $f(y) = x$. The formula you are given gives such a $y$. (This approach is equivalent to finding a right inverse of $f$, i.e., a function $g$ such that $f(g(x)) = x$ for all $x$.)

Comment: Can you please elaborate a little more??

Answer (score 1):

To prove this function is surjective (or onto), we need to prove that for all $x \in \mathbb{R}$ (the co-domain of f) there exists $y \in \mathbb{R}$ (the domain of f) such that $f(y)=x$.

So, let's take any $x \in \mathbb{R}$, then set $y=f(f(x))$.  Clearly $y \in \mathbb{R}$ and $f(y) = f(f(f(x))$ by how we defined $y$, but this means $f(y) = x$ from how $f$ is defined.  So $y$ has the required property, completing the proof.

Comment: You took $y=f(f(x))$ because y is the pre-image of x,right?

Comment: And, one thing, if x is in codomain and y is in domain, then how is the function proved onto for $f(y)=x$? For being onto, every element of codomain should be mapped to some element of domain. Then, $f(y)=x$ proves that the function is onto only if both x and y are in domain. Am I right??

Comment: One of your statements is the wrong way round: if f:A -> B, then A is the domain and B the codomain, so onto requires every element of the codomain should be mapped $\mathit from$ some element of the domain. I was looking for a y in the domain that maps to x, and the answer to that is in the title of your problem!